# How to Get rotated image from camera through windows media foundation

Tags: camera, video-capture, ms-media-foundation

I use the MF_MT_VIDEO_ROTATION attribute，but it does not take effect. The process is as follows:

```
1、hr = m_pReader->GetNativeMediaType(
(DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM,
i,
&pType
);
2、hr = pType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_VIDEO_ROTATION, MFVideoRotationFormat_90);
3、hr = m_pReader->SetCurrentMediaType(
(DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM,
NULL,
pType
);
4、hr = m_pReader->ReadSample(
(DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM,
0,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL
);
```

Where's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`MF_MT_VIDEO_ROTATION` gives you original rotation of the video. To use it in terms of video rotation it is insufficient to change the attribute value, you have to use APIs that actually rotate the frames, such as, for example, [Video Processor MFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/video-processor-mft).